# C++ how to check cin input is A-Z pattern

Tags: c++

C++ how to check `cin` input is `A-Z` pattern

How do i check if the following

`cin >> input;`

and input is `A-Z` , means not number , and is `A` to `Z`;

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `input` is a string you can check for any non-upper case characters using `std::find_if` to look for the first character that isn't suitable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string input;
  std::cin >> input;
  std::cout << (std::find_if(input.begin(), input.end(), std::isupper) != input.end()) << "\n";
}
```

If you have C++11 that simplifies slightly further to:

```
std::all_of(input.begin(), input.end(), std::isupper)
```

Comment: Or take a look at [std::any_of/all_of/none_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - interesting I'd not realised they'd been added in C++11.

Answer (score 1):

Considering input is `string`:

```
bool flag = true;
for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
 if (input[i] < 'A' || input[i] > 'Z') {
  flag = false;
  break;
 }
}
```

Then `flag` shows what you want.
If you use other character tables (other than ASCII, Unicode) then you can use `isalpha` from `cctype`.

Comment: Not portable - for example if you're using EBCDIC this will accept characters such as }, { and \. It'd rather use `std::find_if` too.

Comment: How about using `isupper`? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isupper/

Comment: @Flexo: Portability is relative.  You're much more likely to run into a system for which it's not possible to write C++ than one that uses EBCDIC.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - not much point going out of your way to make something non-portable when there's simpler portable option.

Comment: I think those should be < and > instead of <= and >=

Comment: @Flexo: Agreed, I was about to edit my comment to that effect, but I got distracted.